# Prove $a,b\in R$ are idempotent iff $ab=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

Let $R$ be a ring. An element $a\in R$ is called **idempotent** if $a^2=a$. Suppose that R is a ring with unity $1\neq 0$, and that there are $a,b\in R$ such that $a+b=1$. Prove that $a,b$ are idempotent if and only if $ab=0$.

Even a hint would be awesome. As usual, I feel like the way to start should be really obvious and the proof should be really simple.

Comment: A hint would have been to use $b=1-a$. But complete solutions are more popular ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a + b = 1$, then $b = 1-a$. We then have that the following statements are equivalent:
$$
ab = 0\\
a(1-a) = 0\\
a - a^2 = 0\\
a=a^2
$$
The statement $b^2 = b$ follows the same way.